# Асинхронная очередь запросов на сервер с фиксированным интервалом на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

Есть код синхронного запроса. Синхронный используется потому, что нельзя отправлять параллельные запросы, сервер отвечает не чаще раза в секунду, более частые запросы блокируются. Ну и естественно, есть неприятный момент в виде "подвисания" страницы при выполнении.

```
var strings = document.getElementsByClassName('hidstr');
var tac = document.getElementsByClassName('tac');

for (var i = 0; i < cnnt; i += 1) {
    if (tac[i].offsetHeight > 0) {
        var xmlhttp = getHttp();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', './req/post.php', false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(strings[i].value + '&date=' + st + '&text=' + tac[i].value);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var info = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите превратить запрос в асинхронный, **сохранив фиксированный интервал** в 0.5 секунды. Если интервал не будет соблюдаться, сервер проигнорирует запрос клиента.

Comment: Например можно имитировать параллельные запросы, работать с js возможно не только в основном потоке, параллельно отправляя с основного и с рабочего, для этого существуют [web-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать очередь запросов на основе кода ниже...

```
class Queue {
  constructor(interval = 1000) {
    this._queue = [];
    this._monitor = setInterval(() => {
      const request = this._queue.shift();
      if (request) {
        console.log(request, Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }, interval);
  }
  dispose = () => clearInterval(this._monitor);
  push = (str) => this._queue.push(str);
}

const queue = new Queue(5000);
queue.push("123");
```

Код, помимо значения, выводит [unit timestamp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), чтобы можно было убедиться в интервале исполнения между запросами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заасинхронить с интервалами такой код не составит ни малейшего труда...

```
this._lambda = async () => {
  const request = this._queue.shift();
  if (request) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://${request}`);
    console.log(request, response, Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
    setTimeout(this._lambda, interval);
  } else {
    setTimeout(this._lambda, interval);
  }
}
this._lambda();

...

dispose = () => this._lambda = () => null;
```